# Saying "programming" vs "coding"

Tags: word-choice, formality, programming, business-language, register

I've always thought that "programming" sounded more professional opposed to "coding".  But after looking at the words more closely I'm not entirely sure they mean the same thing.  But even if they do mean the same thing, from another person's viewpoint, is it really more  professional too say "programming" over "coding"?

Comment: Not if you use the terms with accuracy.  If you say programming when speaking of programming and coding when discussing coding you will be impeccably professional.

Comment: @Oldcat The terms are interchangeable.

Comment: No they aren't. No more that writing and typing are interchangable.

Comment: @tchrist  I don't think this question is a duplicate of that question.  This question is asking something else.  (Even though they do have almost the same title, the main question is different in my opinion)

Comment: It is asking exactly the same thing: whether there is a difference between the two words.

Comment: That's not the only thing my question is asking though.

Comment: @Oldcat, if you're going to say they mean different things, please tell us what you think the difference is.

Comment: @Xero, the difference is awfully subtle.

Comment: Programming is a process - you decide the language and platform you need, how to read input data and deliver output data, what data structures and such you need, and the method your program will use to do its task. Then you compose the code in the language. **This one step is 'coding'.**  Then you test the program, fix errors and if necessary redesign and recode.  My analogy to writing a story is a good one. There is more to a story than typing the words on paper.  There are creating a plot and characters, typing in a first draft, editing and rewrites...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over the course of my 15 years as a software developer, usage of *coding* has decreased and people mostly say *programming*. *Coding* is still acceptable and understood, but when in doubt, say *programming*.  And yes, *programming* does sound more professional.

This is assuming you are talking about writing computer software.  There are uses of the word *coding* that do not refer to writing computer software.

Comment: Things are cyclical. Yes, there was a time when *coding* was the usual term, and then it became old-fashioned. It had different connotations back then (coding was a rote task, essentially manual labor; while programming was higher-level, with more creativity and logic). Well, *coding* is back (smartphone developers are referred to as coders, and parents ask if their kids should learn to code), and *programming* is actually (slightly, for now) old-fashioned (because programmers are the ones who still sit at desktop computers and prefer full keyboards).

Comment: I personally like both terms, as well as "Developer". I asked a skilled junior coder of mine what she preferred, and she said she wanted to be called a "Software Engineer" as she thought it conferred more prestige.

Comment: I can't deny being old-fashioned, and I certainly do enjoy my full-sized keyboard.  I'll have to ask the younger "coders" on Monday what they think.  For myself, I prefer Developer because it is encompassing of the other aspects of the job. But I'm happy with programmer or coder since that is 90% of any given day.  Engineer sounds a bit overblown to me but it's so pervasive now that I think it's fine.